# How to set colnames and rownames when you read bunch of files from a directory into R?

Tags: r

I have directory with lot's of files inside of it. I'm trying to read all the files and select the second column of each files and use rbind to create matrix.But the problem is that after creating matrix, there is no colnames and row names in it.
Basically row names should be the file names that I read and ***rbind*** it's second column.  colnames should be the first column of one of the file.

Here is my efforts:

```
nm <- list.files(path="path/to/file")
MyMatrix<-do.call(rbind, lapply(nm, function(x) read.table(file=x)[, 2]))
```

Comment: have you tried setting the row names to what you want?  `row.names(MyMatrix) <- nm`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fake data setup (eg all your files are in `testdir` directory)

```
my.data <- Indometh
write.csv(my.data, file = "testdir/test1.csv", row.names = FALSE)
my.data$time <- my.data$time + 1
write.csv(my.data, file = "testdir/test2.csv", row.names = FALSE)
my.data$time <- my.data$time + 1
write.csv(my.data, file = "testdir/test3.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

Then few changes to your cycle are needed

```
nm <- list.files(path="testdir")
my.file <- paste("testdir", nm, sep="/")
MyDataFrame<-do.call(cbind, lapply(my.file, function(x) {
   col2name <- gsub( "\\..+$","", basename(x))
   my.col <- data.frame(read.csv(file=x)[, 2])
   names(my.col) <- col2name
   my.col

}))

MyDataFrame
```

here it's done with `read.csv`, adapt it to your needs :)

HTH, Luca